# TinyMCE : change default display of text-color inside <textarea>

Tags: tinymce-4

Default text in TinyMCE editor is black until styles are applied either via the plugins or my custom CSS. Once saved and viewed, default text-color is #555, as defined in my primary stylesheet.

I would like TinyMCE to display #555 as the default, to assist users in selecting compatible colors when formatting text via the editor.

Previous questions/answers on StackOverlow (c.2013) refer to a CSS file that no longer exists in the TinyMCE package. I've tried changing the default "color" in *content.min.css* without result.

I've also tried adjusting the CSS that controls the data-entry forms BUT this is not working, eg.
 **`#ppform textarea {color:#555}`**

`<table id="ppform"> 
<tr><td><textarea id="ppmce" name="entry">`

Is is possible? What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to impact the content in the editor via CSS you can pass CSS to the editor via the `content_css` configuration setting:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css

Comment: thanks. I'll keep that in mind BUT at this time I'm not using the "cloud" version. I'm using a local install of 4.8.3 and there's no CSS file with that name.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my reply -  `content_css` is a setting you place in your TinyMCE configuration.  There is no CSS by default that is passed into the editor at which point the skin provides a "default" CSS.  You pass in your own CSS to have the editor look however you like.  This setting is appropriate regardless of whether or not you are using Cloud or Self Hosted.

Comment: Hi Michael,
Thank you! Yes I misunderstood. Hopefully I can fugure out what to do now... I'll read through more docs at Tiny. Many thanks to all those involved in maintaining TinyMCE. Much appreciated.